# What is the opposite of ctrl+click in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Ctrl + click in Eclipse passes to the code of the selected function.

What is the "undo" command? meaning After I did Ctrl+Click how do I auto return to where I was?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To go back to where you came from in Eclipse, choose `Navigate -> Back` from the menu bar, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> [on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227959/what-is-the-opposite-of-ctrlclick-in-eclipse/31228006?noredirect=1#comment95483721_31228006)).

This navigates backwards through the cursor history, and therefore works in general when you need to navigate to a previous position, not only after an `Open Declaration` command.

To navigate forward through the cursor history, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>.

Comment: [Cmd]+[Alt]+[Left] on a mac